# How to split RichTextBox selected text by SelectionFont?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

In my `C#` application, I have a `RichTextBox` which may include some texts with different fonts.

I want to split the selected text in the `RichTextBox` by different fonts and put each part in different `RichTextBox`s.

Something like this

```
string[] fonts = rchNote.SelectedText.Split(rchNote.SelectionFont); //This is where I can't figure out
List<RichTextBox> lstRich= fonts.Select(font => new RichTextBox {Rtf = font}).ToList();
```

Also I want to keep the text style. That's why I used `Rtf = font`.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Provide a sample of what you write in the RTB

Comment: @Sayka Just assume `My name is Alex` which in each word has a different font. I can't provide an actual sample as the editor here doesn't support different fonts.

Comment: Loop through the entire content

Comment: Such a loop will be very time consuming if the content is large.